# How to size my UI components for a Cocoa mac app given the potential variety of resolutions it could be displayed on?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

1. Cocoa uses a drawing system (user coordinate space) measured in "points" which are resolution independent...sounds great
2. While we need to be concerned with our app running in many resolutions, Cocoa is going to take care of that for us in (1) above...sounds too good to be true!
3. It does scale our controls as resolution changes...this is good.
4. BUT the screen size increases as my resolution increases...this is not good, I though we had a drawing canvas that was independent of the resolution!
5. What if the controls shrink to silly small levels as the resolution increases - should I be concerned about this?

To summarize: is their a "standard" resolution I should design for and then all automatic scaling by Apple will automatically look fine?

[Confused while reading the Apple Progammer Guide on the topic of Drawing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to be concerned about this. The user is only allowed to select resolutions which make sense given the physical size of the display, so the standard controls will always be "large enough". You just need to test your app on Retina and non-Retina displays (and ideally both at the same time, with an external 1x monitor plugged on a 2x machine ; move your windows between the two screens and check that your images update accordingly).

Comment: Thanks. At a high level that's good to know. How though can the max (x,y) coordinates change in the user space (as resolution changes) if it's truly a device/resolution independent space? To me that breaks the abstraction.

Comment: It cannot be a device independent space. If you have an external monitor attached and move a window to a larger screen (even if it has the same resolution) the maximum coordinates have to increase. It does try to make drawing independent of the scale factor of the screen, though.